# Facebook Connect: API Features

Tags: facebook, api

I'm building a web site that will use Facebook Connect.  I have a very simple question.

Today: Person A joins the site (via Facebook Connect).

Tomorrow: Person B joins the site (via Facebook Connect).

In 2 Days: Person C joins the site (via Facebook Connect).

None of these people know each other on Facebook or in the real world.

Let's say that Person A "fans" Person B on our web site (unrelated to Facebook).  If Person C has a friend on Facebook who's friends with Person B (B and C are connected... but through a friend... they're friends of friends on Facebook), then can Facebook Connect allow me to tell Person C that they have a distant connection to Person A on our web site?  In other words, can we say: "Person C, congratulations!  You have a friend of a friend on Facebook [Person B] who is a fan of Person A on our separate web site."

Is that possible with Facebook Connect?

Graphically:

A - is fans on separate site with - B

B - is friends of friends on Facebook with - C

Can we tell C that B is connected to A on the separate site?

Thanks!

Mike

Answer (score 0):

There is an API to check whether [two users are friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/common-scenarios#userfriends), but not to check if they have mutual friends. You would have to retrieve every user's list of friends and cross reference them to find mutual friends.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm actually not wondering about mutual friends... I'm wondering if you can check if a friend of a friend is on our site.  In other words, if Person A joins our site, could we check and see if a friend of friend of Person A is on our site?  Like if Tom joins our site and has a friend Jon on Facebook (and Jon is friends with Jim).  Could we use the Facebook API to tell Tom that Jim is on our site?